# MPMusicPlayerController stop and can't resume when play audio from somewhere in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am doing Music App with `iPodMusicPlayerController`.

I am fine play songs from iPod Library.

However one thing.

when i playing songs from iPod Library and i go to safari or something and play music or movie from web , my app stop playing.

After played from web , i go back to my app and tap on play button that isn't work anymore.

Here is my playOrPause action codes.

```
MPMusicPlaybackState playbackState = self.player.playbackState;
    if (playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStateStopped || playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused)
    {
        [self.playOrPauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pauseiCon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.player play];
    }

    else if (playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying)
    {
        [self.playOrPauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playiCon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.player pause];
    }
```

And also i registered Notification.

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for my own question. :D

first register notification with `MPMusicPlaybackStateInterrupted`

We can check Interrupt with that property.

```
MPMusicPlaybackState playbackState = [self.player playbackState];

    if (playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused || playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStateInterrupted)
    {
        [self.playOrPauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playiCon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    else if (playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying)
    {
        [self.playOrPauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pauseiCon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

And add following code in `playOrPause` Action

```
MPMusicPlaybackState playbackState = self.player.playbackState;

    if (playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStateStopped || playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused || playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStateInterrupted)
    {
        [self.playOrPauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pauseiCon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.player play];
    }

    else if (playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying)
    {
        [self.playOrPauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playiCon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.player pause];
    }
```